# append Script tag dynamically using jquery in a form tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am writing code for adding Payment integration. My task is to add script Dynamically through javascript or jQuery.

When I add script tag into my form tag

```
var form_tag = $('<form></form>')
$(form_tag).attr('method' , 'POST')
$(form_tag).attr('action' , '')

var script_tag = document.createElement('script')
$(script_tag).attr(
    {
        type : 'text/javascript',
        src : 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js',
        'data-key' : 'my_razorpay secret key (absolutly correct)',
        'data-amount' : 7200,
        'data-currency' : 'USD',
        'data-buttontext':'Pay With Razorpay',
        'data-name':'Pro Subscription',
        'data-description' : 'Here will be the Description',
        'data-image' :  'Image link to show',
        'data-prefill.name' : 'myName',
        'data-prefill.email' : 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'data-theme.color' : '#F37254'
    }
)

$(script_tag).attr('data-order_id' , 'order_id(which is absolutly correct)')
$(form_tag ').append(script_tag)
```

> When I append my script tag to form tag, it truly appends and show in element DOM (chrome) but not working, but when i
> duplicate this tag through the Chrome Element DOM it runs perfectly.

Anyone can help me in this fast

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged with 'cdn'?

Comment: I would never do the checkout in JS, because the client can always change the price. You should instead have a PHP or something to do the checkout and sent it just the product ID, so the server gets the price from a DB and the price can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by adding the src attribute after appending the script tag into the form tag.

what was happening before when I was getting errors.

I was adding src before adding other data attributes. the script loaded but do not show any response because the script required data attributes to perform an action, when attributes do not find it not show response.

Solution

I added all data attributes before and append the script tag into the form tag. after that i add src attribute, doing this solved my problem